# getting a field from a json object using a "address string" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am new to java script , so my apologies if this is trivial. 
My question is syntactical, if I have an object:

```
this.state = {
  A : {
       B: {
           C : [
             {value : 'bob'},
             {value : 'Jim'},
             {value : 'luke'},
           ]
       }
  }
}
```

and I have a string `location = 'A.B.C[1]'` which describes the location of the data I want.

Why can I not just do  `data = this.state[location].value` ?

and is there a simple "JavaScript" way of getting the data using the location string?

any help would be amazing :)

Comment: There's no built-in tool for that. One term I've seen used for this problem is "object graph navigation". There's at least one good duplicate question on the site, but it's hard to find.

Comment: how is the string generated? This could be an XY problem

Comment: Use a regex on your location to get all the levels

Comment: Hello, little advice, do not use "location", it can be interpreted at window.location

Comment: @charlietfl I have code that relies on that in production :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could split the path and reduce the object.

```js
function getValue(o, path) {
    return path.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.').reduce(function (o, k) {
        return (o || {})[k];
    }, o);
}

var o = { A : { B: { C: [{ value: 'Brenda' }, { value: 'Jim' }, { value: 'Lucy' }] } }};

console.log(getValue(o, 'A.B.C[1]').value); // Jim
console.log(getValue(o, 'A.B.C[0].value')); // Brenda
console.log(getValue(o, 'Z[0].Y.X[42]'));   // undefined
```

For setting a value, you could split the path and reduce the path by walking the given object. If no object exist, create a new property with the name, or an array. Later assign the value.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var way = path.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.'),
        last = way.pop();

    way.reduce(function (o, k, i, kk) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {});
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var test = {};
setValue(test, "foo.name", "Mr. Foo");
setValue(test, "foo.data[0].bar", 100);
setValue(test, "and.another[2].deep", 20);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: was trying to do something like that however, the arrays were messing things up. Will the solution work with arrays at any level? ie "A.B[0].c"

Comment: it works with any level. if a path is not resolvable, then it returns `undefined`.

Comment: fantastic, that is some kind of  sorcery, this works perfectly. another quick question do you have a similar method for setting data ( even if the field is undefined) , like : `setValue(object, path, value)` ? :)

Comment: great I have tested the set and it works .. Thanks for the help :)