# How to convert a list of keys into object?

Tags: javascript

I have data in this form:

```
const data = [
 ["a.b", 1],
 ["a.c.a", 2],
 ["a.c.b", true]
]
```

I want to convert this to:

```
const object = {
 a:{
  b:1,
  c:{a: 2, b:true}
 }
}
```

What would be the simplest way of going about it?

Comment: haha, you're going to have to show what you've tried, but this may be a better fit for codereview with that information.

Comment: some help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42206967/1447675

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235241/4636715) utilizing lodash also approaches for a solution you desire.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use a lodash [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#set) for this task.

```
const result = data.reduce((acc, [path, value]) => {
  return _.set(acc, path, value);
}, {});
```